# How do I output JSchema without the formatting?

Tags: json.net, formatting, jsonschema

This was really easy to do with the original JSON.NET package, you'd just pass **Formatting.None** to the ToString() method and you'd get a nice condensed output. Is there not a similar option for JSchema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a [`JSchema schema`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JSchema.htm), to get compact formatting, you can do:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(schema, Formatting.None);
```

Or

```
using var sw = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw) { Formatting = Formatting.None })
    schema.WriteTo(jsonWriter);
var json = sw.ToString();
```

The latter could be made into an extension method, optionally taking a [`JSchemaWriterSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JSchemaWriterSettings.htm):

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string ToString(this JSchema schema, Formatting formatting, JSchemaWriterSettings settings = default)
    {
        using var sw = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw) { Formatting = formatting })
            if (settings == null)
                schema.WriteTo(jsonWriter);
            else
                schema.WriteTo(jsonWriter, settings); // This overload throws if settings is null
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

And then you could do:

```
var unversionedSchema = schema.ToString(Formatting.None);
var versionedSchema = schema.ToString(Formatting.None, new JSchemaWriterSettings { Version = SchemaVersion.Draft7 } );
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ihtrD3).